# How to set height of combo box drop down list in sapui5?

Tags: css, combobox, sapui5

I need to set max-height for dropdown list in combobox in sapui5. I have tried with the following code.

```
#comboBox1-popup.sapMPopover {
    max-height: 400px;
  
}

#comboBox1.sapMPopoverScroll {
    max-height: 400px !important;
    
}
```

Via css i cant set height for the particular combobox in a project. When i tried "sapMPopover" its changes the height of all the combo boxes in my entire project. I want to set max-height for the particular combo box. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is now direct property for the max-height or access to the popover from xml. You need to wait until the popover list is initialized than you can get it from the ComboBox and add a custom class to it.

In the page controller

```
onAfterRendering: function(){
  this.exec(this);
},

exec: function(self){
  var oCombo = self.getView().byId("MyComboBox"),
  oPopOver = oCombo.getList();
  if(oPopOver !== null
    && oPopOver !== undefined){
    oPopOver.addStyleClass("test");
  }else{
    setTimeout(self.exec, 1, self);

  }
}
```

In the css file you can write now

```
.test {max-height: 100px !important;}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. For me oPopOver = oCombo.getList(); was giving null. This trick of recalling it again worked.